# One-line command exploiting ssh_config for ssh tunneling with local private key

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

#### Context

- **work**, **proxy** and **service** are computers.
- **work** is a multi-users computer.
- I own **proxy**.
- **work** is behind a firewall that restricts **service** access, since **service** entrypoint port (122) is blocked by the firewall.
- I can access over `ssh` **proxy** to then access **service**.
- `priv.key` is the private key to connect to **service** and it must only be on **work** (not **proxy**).

  ```
             firewall
      +-------+  |  +-------+    +---------+
      |  Work |--|--| proxy |----| service |
      +-------+  |  +-------+    +---------+
         `-------------'  `----------' <- port forwarding/ssh tunneling
  ```

---

#### Solution A: *port forwarding*

I can access **service** by executing these two commands:

```
ssh server -L 2222:service:122 -N
ssh -i /home/work-user/.ssh/priv.key -p 2222 service-user@localhost
```

This solution is insecure and not convenient: any user accessing on **work** has also access to `service:122`, and there are two commands.

---

#### Solution B: *ssh tunnel*

I tried to exploit `ssh_config` and configure an ssh tunnel with the following:

```
Host service
    HostName service
    User service-user
    Port 122
    IdentityFile /home/work-user/.ssh/priv.key
    ProxyCommand ssh proxy /usr/bin/nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
    # "proxy" in the previous line is a working ssh alias.
```

However, the `ssh service` command is not successful, here are the logs:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/work-user/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [*authorized algorithms*]
debug1: /home/work-user/.ssh/config line 54: Applying options for test
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/work-user/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [*authorized algorithms*]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh proxy /usr/bin/nc service 122 2>/dev/null
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/work-user/.ssh/priv.key type 4
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/work-user/.ssh/priv.key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I also tried to copy `priv.key` on **proxy**, only to test since I do not want it a permanent solution, but I had the same error.

---

#### Question

Is there a one-line command using `ssh_config` to exploit ssh-tunneling while keeping my private-key on **work** and not **proxy**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a one-line command using ssh_config to exploit ssh-tunneling while keeping my private-key on work and not proxy?

Using `ProxyCommand`, authenticates always from your local computer and not from the `proxy`. Today, you should use `-W` switch instead of `netcat`:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy
```

or `ProxyJump` option, which does it even simpler:

```
ProxyJump proxy
```

Your use case did redirect the errors to the `/dev/null` so even though there would be some errors, you would not see it.

Give it a try with the above and if it will not help, provide the debug logs (using `LogLevel DEBUG3` for **both** of the steps -- proxy and service).